# What Visual Studio Code setting is minifying my html when I close the application?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I tell what extension or setting is minifying my HTML in Visual Studio Code? How can I restore it to being unminified?

Comment: [This one](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HookyQR.minify)?  (Just guessing.  And that's all it will be, is a guess.  If only there was a way to check Visual Studio Code to see which extensions are loaded. [Oh, wait.](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery))

Comment: I should have been more clear. I am aware of extensions, and haven't added a minify extension. None of the extensions I have added (Beautify, ESLint, jshint, Live Sass Compiler, Live server, Python, React Native Tools, SCSS IntelliSense, Simple React Snippets) appear as though they would minify my HTML file on exit which is what apparently is occurring. 

Because it's not something obvious, at least to me, like having installed an extension explicitly for the purpose of minifying is why I asked how I might tell what non-obvious setting or process under the hood might be doing it.